# Double superscript in different positions

Tags: superscripts

I am trying to write the superscript as in the picture, but I  get double superscript error.

[image: Desired Result]

I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $v'_{w_O}^{T}$ % Double superscript error
\end{document}
```

Comment: v'_{w_0}{}^T for example.

Comment: or `v'_{{w_O}^T}`

Comment: or `v'^{T}_{w_O}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
{\mathbf{v}'_{w_O}}^{\!T}\mathbf{h}
\]
\end{document}
```